# Purpose of NSPicturesDirectory in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

In [Foundation Constants Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) what are

```
NSMoviesDirectory
NSMusicDirectory
NSPicturesDirectory
```

If I am working on images am I supposed to store in `NSPicturesDirectory` ?

Comment: Who ever down vote my question I want to tell that in description on this is told "Location of user's Pictures directory (~/Pictures)". So I am not clear thats why I asked. Don't know why people in such hurry to down vote.

Comment: ppl are in a hurry because there a HUNDREDS of (sorry) basic/unuseful questsions.

Comment: your question doesnt show ANY research effort for example :/

Comment: note that I didnt downvote but normally I would

Comment: @Daij-Djan I would like to invite you on this question and please view the answer and comments and help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NSSearchPathDirectory` enum defines folder location where you should store files that are of a certain type.
 
The Idea is that those locations determine paths the user EXPECTS to find apps/docs/pictures/movies...

e.g.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, NSSearchPathDirectory) {
    NSApplicationDirectory = 1,             // supported applications (Applications)
    ...
    NSLibraryDirectory,                     // various documentation, support, and configuration files, resources (Library)
    NSDocumentationDirectory,               // documentation (Documentation)
    NSDocumentDirectory,                    // documents (Documents)
    ...
    NSDesktopDirectory = 12,                // location of user's desktop
    ...
    NSMoviesDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 17,                 // location of user's Movies directory (~/Movies)
    NSMusicDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 18,                  // location of user's Music directory (~/Music)
    NSPicturesDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_6, 4_0) = 19,               // location of user's Pictures directory (~/Pictures)
     ...
    NSTrashDirectory NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE(10_8, NA) = 102                   // location of Trash directory
};
```

Now... the real locations (the file paths) are based on where your app is stored.
Since in IOS there is no user visible filesystem AND especially because every app runs in its own sandbox, they only are of limited use:
they only tell the OS where to find what and it may make assumptions how to treat those locations then: e.g. Caches can be discarded at will, docs must be kept... movies/pics as well

Remember that while IOS only sees caches / anything else, OSX treats the paths differently for sure

Answer (score 1):

You can save images to documents directory, or tmp  directory,to get documents directory you can use the following.

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* dd = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //document directory path
```

By default "Movies","Music" and "Pictures" won't be in the Directory. You have to create the path and place data files.

Eg:NSMoviesDirectory

```
NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSMoviesDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString * documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSError * error;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: documentsDirectory])
{
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
NSString * resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath:[documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"] error:&error];
}
else
{
NSString * resourceDBFolderPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:resourceDBFolderPath toPath: [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sleep.mp4"] error:&error];
}
```

Comment: But what is the purpose of these NSMoviesDirectory, NSMusicDirectory ,NSPicturesDirectory...

Comment: resourceDBFolderPath is /var/mobile/Applications/2EFFBD8D-BEEF-4657-8309-54C7E5BF6B09/test1.app/sleep.mp4 but if you write in main app directory it will change the signature of app and prevent app from relaunching.